# Google Chrome : unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file

Tags: 14.04

I have tried with `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`. It is already present in the system. I tried all solutions available in forums, but they did not work.
I am getting always the same error when running `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 1):

In most of all cases the software sources are not configured correctly - sometimes there are double or wrong entries, so check the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and remove any Google entry that may exist. Open a terminal and execute : `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
Remove all Google lines that might exist and press <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save the changes.

Check for Google entries in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder by executing this command : `sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and delete every Google related`.list` file. Example
to remove `google-chrome.list` : `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

Re - add the Google Chrome repository to the software sources and update the repositories :

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list  
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -  
sudo apt update
```

Now you are able to install Google Chrome or upgrade an existing Google Chrome installation.
Upgrade by : `sudo apt upgrade` or install it with : `sudo apt install google-chrome-stable`